DDD: Value Object with Id
I have a question regarding whether or not 1 of my "classes" in my DDD Test Aggregate constitute a value object or a entity.
Lets say I had 2 aggregates:

TestDefinition
Test

Test contains a link to TestDefinition. Now in normal circumstances just adding a TestDefinitionId on the Test would have been good enough, however I want to store a snapshot of the TestDefinition on my Test (as it were on Test creation).
This snapshot is immutable (like Value Objects usually are), but in theory contains an Id (like Entities usually do). However I feel that this Id is more accidental (and for completeness). I could have quite easily have removed the Id and it would have been of no consequence.
So my question is, is TestDefinition (in the context of my Test Aggregate) a ValueObject or Entity? (and if so what is your reasoning)

In Domain-Driven Design (DDD), the distinction between entities and value objects is important and can sometimes be nuanced. Let's break down your scenario to determine whether the snapshot of TestDefinition within the Test aggregate should be considered a value object or an entity.
Key Characteristics of Entities and Value Objects:
Entities:

Identity: Entities have a distinct identity that runs through time and different states. They are identified by a unique ID.
Lifecycle: Entities typically have a lifecycle, and their state can change over time.
Mutability: Entities are often mutable, meaning their state can change as the system evolves.

Value Objects:

No Identity: Value objects do not have a distinct identity. They are defined by their attributes and are considered equal if their attributes are the same.
Immutability: Value objects are typically immutable, meaning their state cannot change once created.
Equality: Value objects are compared based on their properties rather than any identity.

Analysis of TestDefinition in the Context of Test Aggregate:

Immutability: You mentioned that the snapshot of TestDefinition is immutable within the Test aggregate. This is a strong indication that it could be a value object since immutability is a core characteristic of value objects.

Identity Presence: Although the snapshot contains an ID, you indicated that this ID is accidental and could be removed without consequence. This suggests that the identity is not fundamental to the role of the snapshot within the Test aggregate.

Purpose within the Aggregate: The purpose of the snapshot is to capture the state of TestDefinition at the time of Test creation. This historical snapshot is meant to represent the state, not an ongoing identity. Value objects often serve this purpose well because they capture and convey state without concern for a unique identity over time.


Conclusion:
Based on your description, within the context of the Test aggregate, the snapshot of TestDefinition is best classified as a value object. Here's why:

Immutability: The snapshot does not change once created.
State Representation: The snapshot captures the state of TestDefinition at a specific point in time.
Accidental Identity: The ID in the snapshot is incidental and not fundamental to its role within the Test aggregate.

The presence of an ID does not necessarily make an object an entity, especially if the ID is not used to distinguish the object from other instances in a meaningful way. Since the ID in your snapshot does not play a critical role in its identification within the aggregate, it aligns more with the characteristics of a value object.
